# Catching an exception vs. looping through a collection (the less stupid way)

Tags: c#, exception, enumerable

A company that shall remain unnamed has `IFormsCollection.GetForms("ObjectIndex") || IFormsCollection.GetForms(0)` method that throws an exception if the Form isn't in the collection.  It isn't `IEnumerable<form>` and requires either `for()` loops or `.GetEnumerator()` -> `while()` to get each item in the list.

My question is whether or not I should loop through the IForms collection every time? I need to find a form that won't be in there most of the time, or just skip looping and assume if it throws an exception that it's not there?  I'd rather not maintain a second collection that IS IEnumerable for ease of searching.

Comment: `Do not use exceptions for normal flow of control, if possible.` From [Exception Throwing - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229030(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Don't create a 2nd collection, create a wrapper around this collection that *does* implement IEnumerable

Comment: Note that you can still use a object in a `foreach` loop if it does not implement `IEnumerable<T>` or `IEnumerable`. The spec requires only that it has a `GetEnumerator` method whose return type has a `Current` property and a `MoveNext` method returning a `bool`.

Comment: I've been using while(.MoveNext) {list.AddOrUpdate( ... .Current.GUID, .Current);} to maintain the collection as a ConcurrentDictionary<string,form> since I am calling the methods in parallel on an event.


I just can't see the advantage to having it be a custom collection class when it does Enumerator and nothing else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exceptions kill performance. You could loop obviously if you want, but it be much faster if ou build a dictionary from this collection with the key being the name and value being the form. then simply search the dictionary for the key and that would be hell lot faster and no exceptions

Answer (score 3):

Don't throw exceptions on purpose. They should not be used for normal control flow.